# Can't sticky with display: flex on Safari

Tags: css

It works best on other Browses but not working on Safari when using display: flex.

I see it is fixed 1 roughly equal to the parent's clientWidth.

I think, in the case of using flex, the clientWidth of the sticky area has some problem

Refs:

Link on jsFiđle: https://jsfiddle.net/huynhkhanh226/8tLq45bg/137/

Link on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3f3trspQBuA

Here is my HTML:

```css
table {
                display: table;
                table-layout: fixed;
                border-collapse: separate;
                border-spacing: 0;
            }

            table td,
            th {
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }

            .container {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                width: 100%;
                padding: 5px;
            }

            .sticky {
                height: 150px;
                padding: 10px;
                border: 3px dotted red;
                position: sticky;
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
                width: 300px;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: flex-start;
                align-items: center;
                margin-bottom: 25px;
                align-self: flex-start;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-left: 0;
                overflow-x: hidden;

            }

            .sidebar {
                width: 220px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }

            .mainbody {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                overflow: scroll;
                width: 600px;
                justify-content: stretch;
            }
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

        <div class="container" id="test">
            <div class="sidebar">
                sidebar
            </div>
            <div class="mainbody">
                <div class="sticky">
                    I want this rectangle sticky. <br>
                    it works best on Chrome but it doesn't work on safari.
                </div>
                <div>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="min-width: 540px">Company</th>
                            <th style="min-width: 540px">Contact</th>
                            <th style="min-width: 540px">Country</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 540px">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                            <td>Maria Anders</td>
                            <td>Germany</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="width: 540px">
                            <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                            <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                            <td>Mexico</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Ernst Handel</td>
                            <td>Roland Mendel</td>
                            <td>Austria</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Island Trading</td>
                            <td>Helen Bennett</td>
                            <td>UK</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
                            <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
                            <td>Canada</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
                            <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
                            <td>Italy</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you need. Can you please clarify.

Comment: @harmonica141 I want to use "sticky" to fix the red rectangle when using the horizontal scroll bar. This problem only happened on safari. it works on chrome

Comment: I've had the same issue and wasted a lot lifetime on it to play around with css hacks and stuff. End of the story was, I *can't* do anything to get it to work, **but**: in my current Safari Tech Preview (Release 121 (Safari 14.2, WebKit 16612.1.4.3)) this bug does not exist anymore.